# Complex manifold with conjugate complex structure

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold with complex structure $J$. It is clear that $(M,-J)$ is also a complex manifold.

Under what condition is $(M,J)$ biholomorphic to $(M,-J)$?

Comment: This is certainly the case if $M$ admits a real structure — e.g. $M$ is an algebraic variety defined over $\Bbb{R}$.